# Update a BLOB Image stored in MySQL Database with Django

Tags: mysql, django, blob

I'm storing the images in mysql in a Blob format (BinaryField in Django), the action of adding the image is proecssed well and i can display them easily by adding to the string 'data:image.....'.

The problem is when I try to update an already stored BLOB Image in the database with django.

The code below is for updating the state in the front-end and sending the same element to the backend server :

```
getBase64(event.target.files[0])
                .then((res : string)=>res.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""))
                .then((result : string)=>{
                    setElementToEdit({
                        ...elementToEdit,
                        ["fields"] : {
                            ...elementToEdit["fields"],
                            [event.target.name] : result
                        }
                    })
                })
```

The code below is for getting the data in the backend server and updating the element details:

```
if request.POST.get("jobTitle") == "tl":
        employee = Employee(
            firstName=request.POST.get("firstname"),
            lastName=request.POST.get("lastname"),
            jobTitle=request.POST.get("jobTitle"),
            # method 1 : does not work
            # profilePic=request.FILES.get("profilePic").read()
            # method 2 : does not work
            # profilePic=request.FILES.get("profilePic")
            # method 3 : does not work
            # using the base64 encode & decode 
        )
        employee.save()

        return JsonResponse({"success" : True, "element" : result})
```

Comment: `The problem is when I try to update an already stored BLOB Image in the database with django.` can you share your error problem?

Comment: The problem is that i'm trying different method and it's not working all

Comment: @oruchkin when updating if i send the raw file, it says that cannot accept file, when i encode it to base64 then send it, it says that does not accept string only bytes, when i encode the base64 string to bytes in django and then store, it accepts it but the image cannot be displayed anymore in the front end by adding data:image/png,base6